# Ionic 3 Install on Android - This app has no Android key hashes configured.

Tags: android, ionic-framework, facebook-login

I have an Ionic 3 app that I'm trying to test, which utilizes Facebook login. When installed on iOS devices, Facebook login works like a charm. However, when I install on an Android device and try to sign in, I get this error:

`This app has no Android key hashes configured. Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app-id>`

I haven't had any luck finding any useful guide on how to do this without including the Android SDK.

People have mentioned running a command like this:

`keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

However, I'm not sure what `<RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS>` or `<RELEASE_KEY_PATH>` are supposed to be.

My app is still in "sandbox" mode, I suppose, but all I'm trying to do is install the `.apk` that Ionic creates and have users install it on their devices and this is the error they get.

Does anyone have any insight into what needs to be done here? I've added Android to my Facebook app.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#samples), you need to generate the 28 length character string.

> To run samples apps quickly, you can generate key hashes for your
>   development environments. Add these to your Facebook developer profile
>   for the sample apps. Keytool, for generating the key hashes, is
>   included with the Java SE Development Kit (JDK) that you installed as
>   part of setting up your development environment. OpenSSL is available
>   for download from OpenSSL.

On OS X, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

On Windows, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64
```

This generates a 28 character string.

Go to the [Facebook Developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/). Log into Facebook and, using the dropdown menu in the top-right, go to Developer Settings:

[image]

In your developer settings, select **Sample App** from the menu, and add and save your key hash into your profile:

[image]

You can add multiple key hashes if you develop with multiple machines.

You can now compile and run all of the samples - including those that use Facebook Login.